# CSS change color of specific text instead of all text in that class

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and HTML so my apologies in advance if this is a simple question.

On our website the Color of all the prices is red however i need to be able to adjust the color of one specific instance. The price is all set by one line of code:

```
.price { color: #e72526; }
```

However i need to create a rule that will allow me to adjust the color of just the price for the shopping cart.

Comment: use it with shopping card parent class like .parentclassName .price{}

Comment: If you can create a jsfiddler or jsbin for it, that will be easy to identify exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

**STYLE:**

```
<style>
  .shoppingcart .price { color: #e72526; }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shoppingcart">
  <span class="price">$100</span>
</div>
```